# How to sum up the total based on occurrences in one column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, pivot-table, worksheet-function

```
CUSTOMER_SITE    INVOICE_AMOUNT
95093              14711.65
95093              282240
11111              10
11111              10
11111              10
```

`CUSTOMER_SITE` and `INVOICE_AMOUNT` are two columns.

I want to **sum** the second column based on the occurrences in the first column. Example:

`11111` occurs three times so I want to know this total from column B:

`11111`  10 + 10 + 10 = `30`

Comment: take a look at [Array Formulas](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx), and [Putting array formulas to work](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/putting-basic-array-formulas-to-work-HA001087292.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Range("C2")` stick this formula `=SUMIF(A:A,A2,B:B)`

Click in the right-bottom corner and drag the formula down to the last row presented in column `A` or `B`

[image: drag formula]

Select Columns `A` & `C` » right click » copy

Select Column `D` » Paste Special ( As **`Values`** )

[image: paste as VALUES]

Select Columns `D` & `E` and go to `Data` tab on the top of the toolbar and find `Remove Duplicate`

[image: Remove Duplicate]

Unselect Column `E` and click `OK`

[image: Unselect Column E]

Now your Columns `D` & `E` contain a distinct `CUSTOMER_SITE` and the **total** from the `INVOICE_AMOUNT`

[image: finished]

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a [PivotTable](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/pivottable-i-get-started-with-pivottable-reports-in-excel-2007-RZ010205886.aspx), purpose designed and very easy:

[image: SO18250133 example]